# How to properly color the last rows in a datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am struggling to color the last (and first) row in a `DataGrid` in `WPF`.

I found a way to do the first one by using the code below, it does not seem solid and I cannot get this to work for the last row.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=PreviousData}}" 
             Value="{x:Null}"> 
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/> 
</DataTrigger>
```

Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: You can use [AlternationIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex) to get the row index. You can use it along with `IValueConverter` to compare with `ItemsSource` count to identify the last index. Along with that remember to set `AlternationCount` for your `DataGrid` to the `ItemsSource` count, in order for this to work.

Comment: Hi, I altered your question a bit hoping it will be a bit better received - I don't think the down votes are really deserved.